# MySQL: Sophisticated GROUP BY query

Tags: mysql, group-by

We are trying to find a solution to a problem that I have been able to replicate with an illustrative table.  Here's how the illustrative table is created:

```
create table illustrativeTable
(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  label VARCHAR(4),
  reportingDate DATE,
  attr_1 INT,
  attr_2 INT,
  attr_3 INT,

  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

I have populated the illustrative table as follows:

```
INSERT INTO illustrativeTable(label, reportingDate, attr_1, attr_2, attr_3) VALUES('A', '2018-01-01', '1', '3', '100'),
('A', '2018-01-05', '2', '4', '125'), ('A', '2018-01-07', '2', '5', '125'),
('A', '2018-01-08', '3', '6', '150'), ('A', '2018-01-11', '4', '7', NULL),
('B', '2018-01-02', '1', '3', '50'), ('B', '2018-01-05', '2', '5', '75'),
('B', '2018-01-06', '3', '6', '200'), ('B', '2018-01-16', '3', '5', '200'),
('C', '2018-01-05', '6', '9', '175'),('C', '2018-01-08', '7', '9', '225'),
('D', '2018-01-01', '2', '5', '55'), ('D', '2018-01-15', '3', '6', 85),
('D', '2018-01-21', '4', '7', '75'), ('E', '2018-01-25', '2', '4', '65'),
('E', '2018-01-28', '2', '5', NULL);
```

The query

```
SELECT * FROM illustrativeTable;
```

yields the following output:

```
+----+-------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+
| id | label | reportingDate | attr_1 | attr_2 | attr_3 |
+----+-------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 | A     | 2018-01-01    |      1 |      3 |    100 |
|  2 | A     | 2018-01-05    |      2 |      4 |    125 |
|  3 | A     | 2018-01-07    |      2 |      5 |    125 |
|  4 | A     | 2018-01-08    |      3 |      6 |    150 |
|  5 | A     | 2018-01-11    |      4 |      7 |   NULL |
|  6 | B     | 2018-01-02    |      1 |      3 |     50 |
|  7 | B     | 2018-01-05    |      2 |      5 |     75 |
|  8 | B     | 2018-01-06    |      3 |      6 |    200 |
|  9 | B     | 2018-01-16    |      3 |      5 |    200 |
| 10 | C     | 2018-01-05    |      6 |      9 |    175 |
| 11 | C     | 2018-01-08    |      7 |      9 |    225 |
| 12 | D     | 2018-01-01    |      2 |      5 |     55 |
| 13 | D     | 2018-01-15    |      3 |      6 |     85 |
| 14 | D     | 2018-01-21    |      4 |      7 |     75 |
| 15 | E     | 2018-01-25    |      2 |      4 |     65 |
| 16 | E     | 2018-01-28    |      2 |      5 |   NULL |
+----+-------+---------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Our issue is that we want to retrieve label, reportingDate and attr_3, **from selected tuples**, with the following constraints:
1) attr_2 - attr_1 = 3
2) attr_3 IS NOT NULL
3) In case of multiple hits, the value with the **highest value for reportingDate** is selected

The simplistic query:

```
SELECT label, reportingDate, attr_3 FROM illustrativeTable
WHERE label IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'E') AND (attr_2-attr_1=3)
AND attr_3 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY label;
```

yields the following result:

```
+-------+---------------+--------+
| label | reportingDate | attr_3 |
+-------+---------------+--------+
| A     | 2018-01-07    |    125 |
| B     | 2018-01-05    |     75 |
| C     | 2018-01-05    |    175 |
+-------+---------------+--------+
```

The problem with this result is that for label 'A' the highest reportingDate that meets all the constraints is 2018-01-08.  Similarly for label 'B' the highest reportingDate that meets all the constraints is 2018-01-06.

We would like to tweak the query so that the output looks as follows:

```
+-------+---------------+--------+
| label | reportingDate | attr_3 |
+-------+---------------+--------+
| A     | 2018-01-08    |    150 |
| B     | 2018-01-06    |    200 |
| C     | 2018-01-05    |    175 |
+-------+---------------+--------+
```

I did try some ideas from 
https://paulund.co.uk/get-last-record-in-each-mysql-group
  but I could not get the results I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the output for the highest `reportingDate`, you just need to add that as a constraint to the query. Note that unless you have multiple data values for a given `reportingDate`, you don't need a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT label, reportingDate, attr_3 
FROM illustrativeTable it1
WHERE label IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'E') AND 
      (attr_2-attr_1=3) AND
      attr_3 IS NOT NULL AND
      reportingDate = (SELECT MAX(reportingDate) 
                       FROM illustrativeTable 
                       WHERE label = it1.label AND 
                             attr_2-attr_1=3 AND 
                             attr_3 IS NOT NULL)
```

Output:

```
label   reportingDate   attr_3  
A       2018-01-08      150
B       2018-01-06      200
C       2018-01-05      175
```

If you do have multiple values for a given `reportingDate`, you will need to `GROUP BY label`, and you will also have to decide whether you want the minimum or maximum value of `attr_3`, in which case you would change `attr_3` in the query to `MIN(attr_3)` or `MAX(attr_3)` respectively.

**Update**

Based on the additional criteria specified by OP in a comment below, this is probably the most efficient query to get the desired result. It joins a sub-select of the initial table (with the non-aggregating conditions applied) to two other tables which give the maximum `reportingDate` by `label` and the maximum value of `attr2` by `reportingDate` and `label` respectively, using the `JOIN` condition to then filter out all entries which do not match `MAX(reportingDate)` and `MAX(attr_2)`.

```
SELECT it1.label, it1.reportingDate, it1.attr_3 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM illustrativeTable
      WHERE label IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'E') AND 
            (attr_2-attr_1=3) AND
             attr_3 IS NOT NULL) it1
JOIN (SELECT label, MAX(reportingDate) AS max_reportingDate
      FROM illustrativeTable it1
      WHERE attr_2-attr_1=3 AND attr_3 IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY label) it2
  ON it2.label = it1.label AND it2.max_reportingDate = it1.reportingDate
JOIN (SELECT label, reportingDate, MAX(attr_2) AS max_attr_2
      FROM illustrativeTable it1
      WHERE attr_2-attr_1=3 AND attr_3 IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY label, reportingDate) it3
  ON it3.label = it1.label AND it3.reportingDate = it1.reportingDate AND it3.max_attr_2 = it1.attr_2
ORDER BY it1.label
```

For the sample data the output remains the same however I have tested it with data which triggers the `MAX(attr_2)` condition on [rextester](http://rextester.com/ZTBN23419).

Comment: The query works very well, as per the previous specifications.  There is another constraint (in addition to the three listed in the original posting) that I unfortunately missed out initially  
4) If there are multiple values for a given reportingDate, choose the one where attr_2 has the maximum value